# reusable component in angular

Tags: angular, ng-template

im trying to create my own select component

so the final result will be like that

in app.components.html for example

```
<div>
    <app-my-select [(ngModel)]="val">
        <app-my-option value="1" >one</app-my-option>
        <app-my-option value="2" >two</app-my-option>
        <app-my-option value="3" >three</app-my-option>
        <app-my-option value="4" >four</app-my-option>
    </app-my-select>
</div>
```

in my-select.component.html

```
<input (click)="openPanel()" class="select-value-container" readonly (keydown)="keyDown($event.key)"
       type="text" (blur)="onTouched()" (input)="onInputChange(origin.value)" [disabled]="disabled" [value]="options[index]" #origin>
    
<ng-template #panelTemplate>
  <div class="drop-down">
    <ng-container
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="myOptionTemplate"
      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{optionSelected = 'optionSelected'}">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

-> I used ng-template for select drop down because i want to pass it to CDK overlay and it works fine

my-select.component.ts

```
...
  @ContentChild(NgOptionTemplateDirective) myOptionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
...
```

my-option.component.html

```
<ng-template ng-option-tmp let-optionSelected>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

the issue is how I can project my-option templates inside select component

in another way what i should write in " ngTemplateOutlet " directive

and the final question is how I can get a reference to all my-option templates in my-select component is it bu using '@ContentChildren'

> Updated Quesion:
>
> > how I can get reference to options templates as QueryList of TemplateRef.
> > because for now I can get reference to them as QueryList of MyOptionComponent

> I have another suggestion by using div inside my-option html instead of ng-template so I can use just ng-content and not ng-template-outlet
>
> > but the new question will be how I can pass optionSelected event to parent component I mean my-select component without using ng-template

Comment: There's a lot to look into in the Open Source community, give it a try!
https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+custom+dropdown&oq=angular+custom+drop

Comment: I tried that I found one similar case but in the final he used servises and some old techniques ,I found also ng-select and I get inspiration from it but the bad thing u have to pass a template and not some clean selector as <ng-option>
I want to clone angular material select as possible as I can