# event binding between nested components

Tags: angular, event-handling, ng-template

Supposing that I have two components compA and cmpB
and cmpB used as child of cmpA (like select and option)

```
<div>
   <cmpA>
      <cmpB></cmpB>
      <cmpB></cmpB>
      <cmpB></cmpB>
   </cmpA>
</div>
```

how I can pass click event from cmpB to its parent by using ( ng-template and let-attr directive and ngTemplateOutlet ) I trid it but it didnt works
[reusable component in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511926/reusable-component-in-angular)

because I have another solution but I wont use it bcs its not practical

I will mention it just to understand what I mean

```
<div>
   <cmpA #cmpA1>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp1.fn()"></cmpB>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp1.fn()"></cmpB>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp1.fn()"></cmpB>
   </cmpA>
</div>
<div>
   <cmpA #cmpA2>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp2.fn()"></cmpB>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp2.fn()"></cmpB>
      <cmpB (click)="cmp2.fn()"></cmpB>
   </cmpA>
</div>
```

I want all of that to be "under the hood"

Comment: If you are referencing on select and option for you case, there is no event on <option> tag in js so far...

Comment: I want to create my own custom select and I have to implement that

Comment: Did you try @Output decorator? I mean EventEmitter? That's the standard way to notify the parent component from the child component.

Comment: @RabieDadi javascript does not support events on <option> tag, you can rely only on <select> change event or others...

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that cmpA and cmpB should be aware of each other. In cmpB you can inject cmpA, and then call its methods directly. And the other way round, cmpA can get all child cmpB items via `@ContentChildren` decorator and do smth with them directly (e.g. update their "checked" state).

Angular Material is a good learning source. E.g. you could look at how `MatRadioGroup` interacts with its nested `MatRadioButton`s: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/radio/radio.ts#L487